# Is it possible to temporary disable running all MySQL queries from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

When I am testing some codes, I want to debug codes in end of the file/function.

Eg: I want to check what is the value for `$abc` which was the last line on of the function.

There are multiple MySQL queries in this function just before the last line. When testing I don't want to run those queries. Instead  of commenting them, is it possible to tell don't run any mysql query in this function using PHP?

Comment: If I understand the question properly, you can check the length of the string (assuming you have a string in `$abc`), you can do something like `if(strlen($abc){ //do not execute query } else { // execute  query}`

Answer (score 0):

move $abc to top and print it if it does not depend on sql queries above